# How to serialize and deserialize OOP Python code?

Tags: python, oop, serialization

Let's say I have client-facing classes and sample client code in Python

```py
class OptionBase(object):
    pass

class OptionA(OptionBase):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

class OptionB(OptionBase):
    def __init__(self, g, h):
        self.g = g
        self.h = h

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, run_id):
        self.run_id = run_id

    def go(self):
        pass

#
# driver.py
#
a = A(run_id=123)
option = OptionB(g=2, h=3)
a.set_option(option)
a.go()
```

How should I serialize the above object-oriented client code in `driver.py` (in a database) so that I can deserialize **later** (say, after 1 week) to run the job with `run_id = 123`. The backend code could look like, for example,

```py
b = Backend(run_id=123)
b.run()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Python source code could, of course, be stored as a multi-line text string in the database and later extracted and executed with the built-in `exec()` function. The more common way to serialize/de-serialize Python objects is via the `pickle` module, but that doesn't store the code associated with object — just a reference to the module/script that defines its class (assuming it's not a built-in). It's unclear what code exactly you want to store and what a "run a job" means. I think you need to clarify what you want to do a better and in more concrete terms.

Comment: I think pickling the instance `a` is a good idea. For the `run_id`, my use case is for the client to reference some rows in an input database table with a specific `run_id`. The actual backend will then process those rows, say, after 1 week, where the `run_id` is matched. The challenge is for the backend to remember all client options; notice that the client options are instantiated from a derived class. Thanks.